# Wordpress custom plugin submit form to another form

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am developing a wordpress plugin for a client, basically I have to do some jquery thing on one page and then send that information to a contact form on another page and I am not sure how to do this exactly.
If it were up to me I would use jquery on the whole page and when necessary I would show the form but maybe the client those not want it like that.

How I have it set up now it is all on one php file

fence.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name:       Fence
 * Plugin URI:        
 * Description:       Fence logic.
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * License:           GPL v2 or later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       fence-plugin
*/
 function wp_fence_frontend_scripts() {
 /*Here I add my scripts*/
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wp_fence_frontend_scripts',1000);

 function test(){
   echo '<div class="num1">2</div>';
   echo '<div class="num2">3</div>';
   echo '<div class="result"></div>';
   echo '<button class="resultButton">Get result</button>';
 
   echo '<form action="'.get_admin_url().'admin-post.php" method="post">';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit-form" />';
   echo '<input type="hidden" id="resultEnd" name="resultEnd" value="" />';  
   echo '<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>';
   echo "</form>";
 }
 add_shortcode('fence', 'test'); /*Short code on the page*/
 /*And now when the form submits to admin-post.php it will execute the following function*/
 add_action('admin_post_submit-form', '_handle_form_action'); // If the user is logged in
 add_action('admin_post_nopriv_submit-form', '_handle_form_action'); // If the user in not logged in

 function _handle_form_action(){
   var_dump($_POST);
   /*Here there is another form that customer will have to add name, email, etc and then send email 
 after submit */
 }
```

and this is my js file:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    /*Delete later*/
    
    $( ".resultButton" ).click(function() {
        var num1 = $( ".num1" ).html();
        var num2 = $( ".num2" ).html();
        $( ".result" ).html(num1+num2);
        
    });
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        // let's prevent the default behavior for now,
        // so that we'll have time to include the image data
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the canvas image data
        var result= $( ".result" ).html();
        // let the hidden field we added earlier carry the image data into the upload handler
        $("#resultEnd").val(result);
        // submit the form
        $(this)[0].submit();
        })
});
```

Right now if I do it like this it will submit and open the wp-admin/admin-post.php , but I wanted to know if there is a way that I can call another php file and still keep the styling on the same page, because when I submit it only shows the contact form.

If not then I will just have to do everything through jquery and use ajax to call

Comment: do not understand what exactly wanted to get from another php ? Say just invoke another php then use ajax to invoke (do not need to use jquery for that, ajax work with out) ... you were still on page where call (use ajax call php and after do whatever else is needed ... do not leavee page) ... still see you were using jquery with $ so what big deal to use with ajax also ?

Comment: if call php and get output on screen(with keeping the style ... the look what is the style use it and include in  that php ...)

Comment: Did you try the Code ? If I click submit It opens admin-post.php and you would see the result of var_dump,what i want to do is submit that form and then get another form were I need to fill in more input fields to send in anotther form

Comment: Do not have to try the code, listing is enough. Didn't quite understand what was the purpose. `submit` is redirect to 'admin` and there the control is not yours.(as you said). As far as i see what you can do is before submit or when intercept. So if you add another form there it will be render ? (if yes then is straight forward ... if not and render admin.php then you could try to add your form before submit after `#resultEnd.val` ... Or just call the admin with ajax and get what-ever needed from them and after render your form ...